# Problem writing syntax when using ngIf to change images in Angular 8

Tags: html, css, angular, image, angular-ng-if

i am new to Angular world and having problem of writing code or syntax to show different images based on the ngx-translate methods. Lets say when the user select English in the language selector, the english wording of image will appear; Else if the user select Mandarin in the language selector, the mandarin wording of image will appear. The ngIf coding i put is like this:

Below is the related coding in both ts and html files, thanks for helping me ya :)

.ts file:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbCarousel, NgbSlideEvent, NgbSlideEventSource } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  animate,
  transition
} from '@angular/animations';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {_} from '@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract/dist/utils/utils';
import defaultLanguage from "../../assets/i18n/en.json";
//import {imgArray} from '../../assets/i18n/en.json';
//import * as dataJSON from '../../assets/i18n/en.json';


@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-carousel-pause', 
  templateUrl: './carousel-pause.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styles:[`
  .carousel-item
  {
    display:block;
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 2s;
  }
  .carousel-item.active
  {
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
    transition: opacity 2s;

  }
  .carousel-control-next-icon {

    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3e%3cpath d='M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-1.568 18.005l-1.414-1.415 4.574-4.59-4.574-4.579 1.414-1.416 5.988 5.995-5.988 6.005z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");

  }  

  .carousel-control-prev-icon {

      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3e%3cpath d='M0 12c0 6.627 5.373 12 12 12s12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12-12 5.373-12 12zm7.58 0l5.988-5.995 1.414 1.416-4.574 4.579 4.574 4.59-1.414 1.416-5.988-6.006z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");

  }

  .form-control{
    width: 200px !important;
    height: 30px;
  }

  .account-form{
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
`]

})
export class NgbdCarouselPause {

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.setTranslation('en', defaultLanguage);
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
}

useLanguage(language: string) {
  this.translate.use(language);
}

  //readJSON = dataJSON;

  //constructor(){
    //this.images2 = imgArray;
  //}
    images = [
        "assets/banner1.jpg",
        "assets/banner2.png",
        "assets/banner3.png",
        "assets/banner4.jpg",
        "assets/banner5.jpg",
        "assets/banner6.jpg"

    ];

  paused = false;
  unpauseOnArrow = false;
  pauseOnIndicator = false;
  pauseOnHover = true;

  @ViewChild('carousel', {static : true}) carousel: NgbCarousel;

  togglePaused() {
    if (this.paused) {
      this.carousel.cycle();
    } else {
      this.carousel.pause();
    }
    this.paused = !this.paused;
  }

  onSlide(slideEvent: NgbSlideEvent) {
    if (this.unpauseOnArrow && slideEvent.paused &&
      (slideEvent.source === NgbSlideEventSource.ARROW_LEFT || slideEvent.source === NgbSlideEventSource.ARROW_RIGHT)) {
      this.togglePaused();
    }
    if (this.pauseOnIndicator && !slideEvent.paused && slideEvent.source === NgbSlideEventSource.INDICATOR) {
      this.togglePaused();
    }
  }
}
```

.html file:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">


      <ngb-carousel #carousel interval="3000" [pauseOnHover]="pauseOnHover" (slide)="onSlide($event)">
        <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let img of images; index as i">
          <!--<div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>My slide {{i + 1}} title</h3>
          </div>-->
          <a href="https://www.google.fr/?q=Number+{{i+1}}" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">
            <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
              <img class="img-fluid class mx-auto" [src]="img" alt="My image {{i + 1}} description">
            </div>
          </a>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-carousel>


    </div>
      <!--
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="pauseOnHover" [(ngModel)]="pauseOnHover">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="pauseOnHover">Pause on hover</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="unpauseOnArrow" [(ngModel)]="unpauseOnArrow">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="unpauseOnArrow">Unpause when clicking on arrows</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="pauseOnIndicator" [(ngModel)]="pauseOnIndicator">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="pauseOnIndicator">Pause when clicking on navigation indicator</label>
      </div>
      <button type="button" (click)="togglePaused()" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">
        {{paused ? 'Cycle' : 'Pause' }}
      </button>
      -->




    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div ngIf="translate==='en'">
        <img src="./assets/opening-account.png" class="img-fluid">

      </div>



      <!--</div>-->  


        <!--<div class="img-fluid">
            {{ 'imgArray.img' | translate }}
        </div>-->

        <div class="account-form">
          <form class="form-inline">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Firstname" aria-label="Search">
              <br><br>
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Lastname" aria-label="Search">
              <br><br> 
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Email" aria-label="Search">
              <br><br> 

          </form>
        </div>

        <img src="./assets/joinnow.png" class="img-fluid">
    </div>




  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use translate currengLang method

change this line

```
<div ngIf="translate==='en'">
```

to this line

```
<div ngIf="translate.currentLang === 'en' ">
```

Comment: Ticked ady. Btw, i noticed the image only appeared if the user select those language. If the page loaded and the user didn't select any language, the image won't appear, is there anything i left out?

Comment: @Shen initialize the value of translate on ngOnInit